# Tweepy not returning full tweet: tweet_mode = 'extended' not working

Tags: python, string, list, twitter, tweepy

Hello I am trying to scrape the tweets of a certain user using tweepy.
Here is my code :

```
tweets = []
username = 'example'
count = 140 #nb of tweets
try: 
    # Pulling individual tweets from query
    for tweet in api.user_timeline(id=username, count=count, include_rts = False):
    # Adding to list that contains all tweets
      tweets.append((tweet.text))
except BaseException as e:
      print('failed on_status,',str(e))
      time.sleep(3)
```

The problem I am having is the tweets are coming back unfinished with "..." at the end.

I think I've looked at all the other similar problems on stack overflow and elsewhere but nothing works. Most do not concern me because I am **NOT dealing with retweets** .

I have tried putting `tweet_mode = 'extended'` and/or `tweet.full_text` or `tweet._json['extended_tweet']['full_text']` in different combinations .

I don't get an error message but nothing works, just an empty list in return.
And It looks like the documentation is out of date because it says nothing about the 'tweet_mode' nor the 'include_rts' parameter : 
[image]

Has anyone managed to get the full text of each tweet?? I'm really stuck on this seemingly simple problem and am losing my hair so I would appreciate any advice :D 
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR: You're most likely running into a Rate Limiting issue. And use the `full_text` attribute.

Long version:

1. First,

   > *The problem I am having is the tweets are coming back unfinished with "..." at the end.*

   From the Tweepy documentation on [Extended Tweets](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#compatibility-mode), this is expected:

   > #### Compatibility mode
   >
   > ... It will also be discernible that **the `text` attribute of the Status object is truncated as it will be suffixed with an ellipsis character**, a space, and a shortened self-permalink URL to the Tweet.
2. Wrt

   > *And It looks like the documentation is out of date because it says nothing about the 'tweet_mode' nor the 'include_rts' parameter :*

   They haven't explicitly added it to the documentation of each method, however, they specify that [`tweet_mode` is added as a param](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#standard-api-methods):

   > ### Standard API methods
   >
   > Any `tweepy.API` method that returns a Status object accepts a new `tweet_mode` parameter. Valid values for this parameter are `compat` and `extended` , which give compatibility mode and extended mode, respectively. The default mode (if no parameter is provided) is compatibility mode.
3. So without `tweet_mode` added to the call, you do get the tweets with partial text? And with it, all you get is an empty list? If you remove it and immediately retry, verify that you still get an empty list. ie, once you get an empty list result, check if you keep getting an empty list even when you change the params back to the one which worked.

   Based on [bug #1329 - API.user_timeline sometimes returns an empty list](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1329) - it appears to be a **Rate Limiting** issue:

   > [Harmon758](https://github.com/Harmon758) commented [on Feb 13](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1329#issuecomment-585763438)
   >
   > This API limitation would manifest itself as exactly the issue you're describing.
4. Even if it was working, it's in the `full_text` attribute, not the usual `text`. So the line

   ```
   tweets.append((tweet.text))
   ```

   should be

   ```
   tweets.append(tweet.full_text)
   ```

   (and you can skip the extra enclosing `()`)

---

- Btw, if you're not interested in retweets, see [this example](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#examples) for the correct way to handle them:

  > Given an existing `tweepy.API` object and `id` for a Tweet, the following can be used to print the full text of the Tweet, or if it’s a Retweet, the full text of the Retweeted Tweet:
  >
  > ```
  > status = api.get_status(id, tweet_mode="extended")
  > try:
  >     print(status.retweeted_status.full_text)
  > except AttributeError:  # Not a Retweet
  >     print(status.full_text)
  > ```
  >
  > If `status` is a Retweet, `status.full_text` could be truncated.

Comment: Thank you that was a very complete answer, I will look through all these things and get back to you!

Comment: I think you might be right about it being an API limitation (not that I fully understand the concept). I tried again and it seemed to work with both .full_text and tweet_mode='extended'. But then with more tests, it went back to returning an empty list. I don't really understand how to fix this problem...

Comment: It's not a problem you can "fix". Twitter is rate-limiting you from data-mining/ddos'ing. Read more about that here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting. Since you're in 15 minute buckets, quickest fix is to start a timer before everything and when you first get an empty list response, wait for the remaining 15 minutes before sending the next request. TBH, that's a pretty silly solution. Unfortunately, Tweepy doesn't seem to let you access the response headers, which include that info. So you have no way to check for those mentioned on the page. Optionally...

Comment: ...Optionally, you could use the [Streaming API](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html) which includes Rate-Limit checking, though probably with the same limits.

Comment: ah ok thank you I understand better. I may try streaming !

Answer (score 1):

As per the twitter API v2:

`tweet_mode` does not work at all. You need to add `expansions=referenced_tweets.id`. Then in the response, search for `includes`. You can find all the truncated tweets as full tweets in the includes. You will still see the truncated tweets in response but do not worry about it.